# Database for Movie ShowTime

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures, database-schema

I create one database that is theatre. In that Movie,Cinemas tables are created, but now i want to create showtime table in my database so i have confusion that how to make that table,how many fields are put in that table and how to store time of show in that.I want to put show time with price that is silver, gold, and platinum.

If there is any idea then tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in `showtime` you basically should have the columns

```
stmid int,              -- pointing to entry in movie table
stcid int,              -- pointing to entry in cinema table
ststart datetime,       -- the actual "showtime"
stprice float           -- ticket price
```

And then define stmid,stcid to be the Primary Key like

```
PRIMARY KEY (stmid,stcid)
```

I would not assign silver, gold or platinum directly in the table but leave that to a later stage, either in a QUERY or a VIEW, depending on criteria that might change over time. The price on the other hand is a very concrete and fixed data type.

**2. Edit**:

To select the movies that will play within the next 24h you could use the following:

```
SELECT mname,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(ststart,'%l:%i %p') ORDER BY ststart) mtimes 
FROM movies 
INNER JOIN showtime ON stmid=mid   
WHERE mname LIKE '%name of movie%' AND ststart BETWEEN NOW() AND ADDDATE(NOW(),1)
GROUP BY mname
```

This statements assumes that there are columns `mid` (unique movie ID) and `mname` (movie name) in table movies.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. I want to display the shows in a way if the current time is 2:00 PM, then the user should be able to see only those shows which are after 2:00 PM not before 2:00 PM. Kindly reply me for the same.!

Comment: Use a select statement that compares the movie time to the current time like `SELECT * FROM showtime WHERE ststart>NOW()`

Comment: Thanks, But in above table you mentioned the user enter time separately then data are go so far and site will be slow. Suppose If in my city there are 100 theatre and in one theatre 5 movie are running and one movie can running in many time like 10:00 AM,11:30 AM,3:00 PM,5:00 PM in different screen. If user enter all time in different rows then site is too slow. If there is any possibility that one movie time can store in one row and how to filter it? Kindly reply me.!

Comment: SQL servers usually don't mind processing many many lines if they are placed in an indexed table. So a line for every starting time for each individual movie/cinema event is the best way of dealing with the task in an SQL environment. Storing multiple data entries into one or several fields of one row is not considered good style since access to the individual data components is relatively expensive. All searches have to considere either multiple columns or the fields will have to be split.

Comment: are you sure it won't get slow even if there are 5 lack entries in the table?

Comment: What do you mean by "lack entries": something like superfluous or redundant or missing? If you want to make sure the performance is best you should also introduce an index on column ststart: `CREATE INDEX IX_start ON showtime(ststart)`

Comment: Thanks, when i select or filter movie by time that time movie name are display many times but i want movie name only one time and all the show time that movie has?

Comment: hello cars, now i have a problem with insert record in nested grid view record cant insert in database.

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail? Maybe this should go in a separate thread? The original post was concerned with database issues only and did not mention any `grid view` connection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my model for the same need, it is not specific to a database but gives you an I idea on the way you may design this entity.

```
  Showtime {
   id: string; //unique id
   movieId //references the movie
   venueId //references the venue where the showtime is occuring
   language: string; //main movie language with subtitles or not
   date: string;     // date time for the showtime 
   video_format: string; // 3D, Imax...
   premiere: boolean; //indicates if it's a movie premiere
}
```